# How to setup staging, pre-prod for google dataflow jobs?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

Say we have a dataflow job:

1. Written in Apache Beam Java SDK which is a Gradle project.
2. Uses pubsub stream as input, writes results to bigtable and writes logs to BigQuery.

As with deploying a server, we can easily have a staging, pre-prod and prod environment.

I want to know what is the "idiomatic" way to do this in Apache Beam & dataflow.

Comment: Did you check this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/building-production-ready-data-pipelines-using-dataflow-deploying)? Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I didnt read this doc. This is what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official google docs have an article on this which answered a lot of my questions.

Here is the article:

https://cloud.google.com/architecture/building-production-ready-data-pipelines-using-dataflow-deploying

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).